# Some 阿-prefix Sichuanese Hakka words (阿妹, 阿姐, 阿妈, 阿孃, 阿祖) - what do they mean?

Tags: meaning

Sichuanese contains a lot of words from other topolects (Hakka, Min, Cantonese, etc.) thanks to the great migration.

There are a bunch of 阿-prefixed forms of address

《四川方言词典》explains:

[image: 阿]

> 阿 a1 (缀)
>
> 用在某些亲属名称的前面（川西部分地区）：～爹|～伯|～哥。

While also offering the following examples:

[image: 阿]

> 阿爸 a1 ba2 (名) 叔父。
>
> 阿伯 a1 be2 (名) ①上了年纪的父亲。②伯父。
>
> 阿爹 a1 die1 (名) 指年轻的父亲。
>
> 阿兄 a1 xiong1 (名) 弟弟 (同“阿哥”相对)。

Here 阿哥 is clearly, also marked as a an 阿-prefixed Sichuanese Hakka form of address - meaning 哥哥 presumably.

《雨城方言》also lists

> 阿妹
>
> 阿姐
>
> 阿妈
>
> 阿孃
>
> 阿祖

What do these words mean:

阿妹, 阿姐, 阿妈, 阿孃, 阿祖?

I can guess, but I'm sure I won't be right. (They very well might differ from proper Hakka, as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.syndict.com/):

阿:

> 釋義： 1.放在稱謂（如爸、嬸、公、姐等）前，表尊敬。2.放在名字前，表親切，同輩之間或長輩稱呼晚輩時使用。  用例：
>   1.阿爸、阿媽、阿公、阿婆、阿叔、阿嬸……2、阿明、阿小珠、阿飛……

阿妹: 1. 孩子（不管晚輩男女，長輩都可稱其阿妹）。2. 女孩子。

阿姐: 姐姐（部分地區也指姑姑）。許多地區稱姐姐為“阿姊”。

阿妈: 媽媽，母親。

阿孃: 1、伯母，伯父的妻子（五華、惠州等地）。2、泛指老婦女。

阿祖: unable to find; I guess it might belong to meaning 2: "放在名字前，表親切，同輩之間或長輩稱呼晚輩時使用。" So, 祖 might be just a person's name.

Comment: 阿祖 could be the same as this one http://twblg.dict.edu.tw/holodict_new/result_detail.jsp?n_no=4604&curpage=1&sample=%E9%98%BF&radiobutton=1&querytarget=1&limit=100000&pagenum=1&rowcount=49 釋義  曾祖父母。稱謂。稱呼祖父的父母親。

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/934/

*[1] [n] prefix to a name or term of address*

> What do these words mean:
>
> 阿妹, 阿姐, 阿妈, 阿孃, 阿祖?

- **prefix to a name**: adding 阿 before a noun indicates it is a name, e.g. 阿豬, 阿狗 (if you only say 豬 or 狗, people would presume you are talking about an anime)
- **term of address**: adding 阿 before the name or title of someone indicates you are addressing that person. ( if you only say 妹, 姐, 孃 or 祖, they might not know you are addressing them or just acknowledging their present, like a kid looking at an apple and say  "Apple!" ) ; you can also address 阿妹, 阿姐, 阿妈 in third person, for example, 我阿妹, 我阿姐, 我阿妈 instead of 我的妹妹, 我的姐姐, 我的妈妈

Comment: If 阿爹 is (指)年轻的父亲 and 阿伯 is 上了年纪的父亲 ---- then I doubt it is that **simple** - otherwise I wouldn't need to bother asking this question........ 阿妲 means: 伯母、伯娘、婶娘 |||| 阿宝 means 表兄妹或表兄弟的统称，即老表 -----

Comment: @user3306356 It might be regional I think.

Comment: Yes @dan dan I’m specifically asking about Sichuanese Hakka as I mentioned multiple times in my question.

Answer (score -1):

Let's keep it **simple**:

If you are a American or familiar with them, you must hear that someone whose name is Lawrence/Timothy/George..... sometimes also can be referred by Larry/Tim/Georgie....

Now you're witnessing the Chinese version of it. And the Chinese version also add rules like Father->something like "Fatherie"? I make it up myself.